# How to run mv command run recursively in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

My environment: Bash 3.5 LinuxRedhat

I'm using the following code to rename all of my files in a single directory.

```
for file in *.* ; do mv "$file" "Add_$file" ; done
```

Now, I want to rename my file recursively.And I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first ideas with find don't work, because {} returns ./ with the command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -execdir mv {} Add_{} ";"
```

We need something, which removes the ./ in front but works in subdirectories too.

```
echo 'f=$(basename "$1"); mv "$f" Add_"$f";' > adhoc.sh
chmod a+x adhoc.sh
find . -type f -name "*.*" -execdir $PWD/adhoc.sh "{}" ";"
```

At least this works for `gnu-find`. Other finds might not have an `-execdir` command.

Thanks for skyking for pointing my error out.

For Linux, you might find a version of 'rename' in the repository, but normally it has to be installed and isn't part of the standard installation. If you often rename with the commandline, it is worth the effort. With **rename**, you specify a regex substitute command and can test it first:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n "s/(.*)/Add_\1/" {} ";"
```

Comment: Does this even work? Here `{}` will be replaced by `./<filename>` making `Add_{}` expand to `Add./<filename>`. Also note that according to the documentation `-execdir` should be on the form `-execdir command {} +` or `-execdir command ;` - which doesn't match your usage.

Comment: You're right, I corrected my post and am a bit astonished about the peer review quality of SE :) . The ";" has to be masked to be prevented from interpreting by the shell - it is not part of the find syntax.